# Redux: dispatch when a component / function is initialised

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a state, that I only want to change when a certain funcitonal component is initialised. So I intend to do somethin like this:

```js
export default function SalesFeedPage(){

 const {salesFeed} = useSelector((state) => state.feedReducer);
 const dispatch = useDispatch();
 // i want to do sth like this
 // useEffect(() => dispatch(loadSalesFeed()), []);
 // or
 // dispatch(loadSalesFeed());
 return (
  <div>
   hello
   {salesFeed}
  </div>
 )
}
```

This doesn't work since it infinitely re-renders the SalesFeedPage.

Is there a way to achieve what I want in a funcitonal component?

Comment: remove the outer dispatch call

Comment: keeping only `useEffect(() => dispatch(loadSalesFeed()), []);` causes `useEffect must not return anything besides a function, which is used for clean-up. You returned`

Answer (score 0):

Just keeping the first useEffect should work, but make sure to only return cleanup functions inside of your useEffect, not your dispatch return value. Like so,

```
useEffect(() => { dispatch(loadSalesFeed()) }, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use,

```
 useEffect(() => dispatch(loadSalesFeed()), [])
```

if you use Dispatch outside the `useEffect` without dependency array, your component continuously getting re rendering. That because ,when you component mounting your dispatch function get called, so your redux state get changed, then again your component get rendered. Then your dispatched is called again. Then this make your component get render again. This lead to infinite rendering cycle.

Hope this help to you!